# Spring boot jackson properties not used

Tags: json, spring, hibernate, jackson, spring-boot

I have a little spring boot application that send request via JSON to a server.
I configured the application.properties like this:

```
spring.jackson.deserialization.fail-on-unknown-properties=true
spring.jackson.serialization.indent_output=true
spring.jackson.serialization.write_null_map_values=false
```

but when I send my object I got an error of lazy initialization:

```
2015-08-03 18:21:04.455 ERROR:SynchroRequest - Could not write content: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.domitik.domitikCDB.model.Box.users, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: ....); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role:
```

It seems that the definitions are not used / loaded.

I also try to make my own ObjectMapper without any result:

```
 ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
    om.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_NULL_MAP_VALUES,false);
    om.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT,true);
    om.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);

 restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(om));
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong ?
Thanks,

Comment: As far as I know, the three properties you have configured won't help with the exception that you're seeing. Can you explain why you think they will?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson because jackson by default will try to get all persistence set (child set)  of an object when serializing it. In server side (spring MVC with tomcat server) I saw the same issue and configured it with my own objectMapper and it's work fine.